# Are there any services out there that will let me convert an URL to PDF and let the user download the result?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a lot of different sites written in PHP (Drupal) and more and more often clients ask me to create PDFs of various lists, product descriptions and so on.. I've been using dompdf and other pdf libraries but they are a pain to use and have a very limited functionality.

Are there any services out there that'll let me generate a PDF file from a URL and let the user download the result? That would definitely save my day :)

Best regards, 
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert html to PDF, then there are a couple of *services* out there which can do that for you ([search](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+to+pdf)), but from the top of my head [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) does a pretty ok job. The basic idea if that if you can generate PostScript from your source, then creating a PDF is not an issue.

If you are looking for a more feature full library then [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) can do it (Java though and not free for commercial use).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I just need a simple service like this one: 
1) I make a request to in example: http://www.1337html2pdf.com/?url=stackoverflow.com
2) The reply is a direct file download of the generated PDF file og the stackoverflow.com site. 

Basically it's the same thing as just doing this on my Mac: 
1) Open a web page page with my browser. 
2) Choose "Print". 
3) Choose "Save as PDF". 

I need this as a transparent service and pricing really isn't an issue.

There are sites out there (but they're not services):
http://www.pdfonfly.com/
http://pdfmyurl.com/

Comment: Can't you use something like http://html2pdf.seven49.net/Web/en/Support/Parameters_for_html2pdf.htm
It seems to do what you want, ie do a request containing the url you want to convert and it returns the PDF. A simple `curl` call should do the trick for you?

Comment: If it works out for you, please mark this as the correct answer.